# My wife and I work for same employer. What are our options for health insurance?

Tags: insurance, family

My wife and I work for the same employer (a school district).  My school offers full single coverage or $14,000 towards family coverage.   A single policy costs $12,000, and a family plan costs $28,000.   Is it legal for my wife to take single coverage and myself to take the family plan?

They are unwilling to put the money of a single cost towards the family plan.

Comment: For questions of legality, we need to know the country (and possibly state) that you are in.

Comment: Does the district offer you any extra money if you decline health insurance?

Comment: Is it _legal_? There may not be a law against it, but the school district or insurer may not allow it.  Have you checked with the benefits department or administrator?

Comment: I don't see why you can't. If you're asking if it's legal for your wife to have double health insurance coverage, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 8):

You have to sit down with HR for the school district. The options involved with with parents working for the same employer can be handled multiple ways. Unless you are a very small district, this situation has come up before.

They will tell you what they allow, and then you have to determine which one saves you the most money. Also look into how the deductibles will work with the two policies. You also need to look at options for the two policies. For example if there are different levels of dental: you may not want to cover an orthodontist  on the single plan.